# TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined? Formidable

Tags: node.js, post, path, cloudinary, formidable

I am making a MERN application and when making a Post request in my routes using Formidable and Cloudinary. 'path' is undefined. When previously creating the route it worked in Postman. but after trying to make an axios call on the client side I would get a typeError saying that 'path was undefined. this has to do with the image that is being uploaded with the form using Cloudinary, but I don't understand why path is undefined?

[image: terminal error]

backend route

```
// const express = require('express')
// const router = express.Router()
const router = require('express').Router();
const {House} = require('../../Models/House');
const Formidable = require('formidable');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require("dotenv").config()
// const { request, response } = require('express');
// const dotenv = require("dotenv");


// dotenv.config();


//mongoDB and Cloudinary

const mongoURI = process.env.Mongo_URI;

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key:process.env.API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET
})


mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true}, (error)=>{
    if(error) {
        return console.log(error)
    }
    return console.log("database is connected")
})

router.post("/api/house-listing", (request, response)=>{
    const form = new Formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(request, (error, fields, files)=>{
        const {
            price,
            city,
            county,
            numOfBeds,
            numOfBaths,
            numOfGarages,
            isSaleOrRent,
        } = fields

        const { houseImage } = files;

        cloudinary.uploader.upload(houseImage.path, {folder:'/houseAgency/houses'}, async(error, result)=>{
            if(error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
            const image_url = result.url;

            const newHouse = new House({
                house_location: {
                    
                    county: county,
                    city: city,

                },

                house_details: {
                    price: price,
                    numOfBeds: numOfBeds,
                    numOfBaths: numOfBaths,
                    numOfGarages: numOfGarages,
                    isSaleOrRent: isSaleOrRent,
                    house_image: image_url,
                }
            })
            const savedHouse = await newHouse.save();
            return response.status(200).json(savedHouse)
        })
    })
})



module.exports = router;
```

Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const HouseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    house_location: {
        city:{type:String, required: true},
        county:{type:String, required: true}
    },

    house_details: {
        price: { type: Number, required: true},
        isSaleOrRent: {type: String, required: true},
        numOfBeds: {type: Number, required: true},
        numOfBaths: {type: Number, required: true},
        numOfGarages: { type: Number, required: true},
        house_image: {type: String, required: true}
    }
});


const House = mongoose.model("House", HouseSchema);
module.exports = {House}
```

Comment: The error is returned since the `houseImage` is undefined rather than 'path' itself. Since you're assigning `files` to it earlier it means that it couldn't extract any files as part of the form's POST request. Could you log the value of `files` before it's assigned to `houseImage` to see the content?

Comment: thanks, I found the problem I should've been using house_image instead.